# Firefox snap package: how do I open downloaded files?

Tags: firefox, downloads

Firefox 75.0 (64bit)came preinstalled as snap package on Ubuntu 18.04, but has been giving trouble since

The only way I can view a downloadable file is by saving it somewhere in my home directory and then open it which is a pain!

The open with dialog box in firefox preferences only gives url script handler and firefox browser as options neither of which work

It looks like firefox doesn't handle anything beyond home directory, while  chrome does instead

Any clues

Comment: Paragraph #3 looks like a bug report - please report it properly to the Ubuntu Bug Tracker.

Comment: Mean this? The open with dialog box in firefox preferences only gives url script handler and firefox browser as options neither of which work. Being a novice please expand on how to report properly.

Comment: Try the Search box at the top of the page: "How do I file a bug report?"

Comment: Thanks; looks like hard work...

Comment: The only useful way to get a bug fixed is to report it with enough detail for a developer to reproduce the issue reliably on a test system. Yes, reporting the first bug is hard. The first *anything* you do is often hard. Sorry.

Comment: Some of us use a snadboxed version of browsers for extra security. While I love the snap version of Opera which worked great from the first day, Firefox's snap implementation is the example of a heart-less very minimal effort. It has some well known less-effort bugs (bugs which shouldn't be hard to fix) and usability issues which I'm sure won't be fixed in the near future.

Comment: The first commenter is incorrect. The report does NOT go to the Ubuntu Bug Tracker since this is a snap issue. The path to find out where to submit an issue is to use `snap info firefox`, go to the webpage, and scroll down to a tiny-ass link at the bottom that says to join https://forum.snapcraft.io to submit an issue. Doing that, I found someone already submitted something similar: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-77-cannot-download-anything/18167

Comment: It is now 2023 and forced-using firefox snap in 22.04 this is still infuriating without solution. Maybe there is this secret plan that snap wants to be hated.